# Install single package from git

Tags: ros, catkin, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Is it possible, using rosws, to install just a single package from a repository? For example I need just the map_server package form the navigation repository. Right now I clone the entire navigation repository, move the map server out of there and remove the navigation repository again, but there must be a better way?

Best regards,
Hans

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98636/install-single-package-from-git/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can only fetch full source repositories from DVCS like GIT / HG (in a reasonable way). But generally you might want to consider to download the latest released version of a package. You can do this using the `rosinstall_generator` (http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1